# Estimation of Surface Normal in a Dense Range Image

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the surface normal estimation proposed by [Hinterstoisser et al (2011)](http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/hinterstoisser_iccv11.pdf) but I'm not clear with some points:

1. In equation (9), is D(x) corresponding to the depth value (Z-axis) at pixel location x?
2. How to estimate the value of the gradient ▽D using 8 neighboring points around the point of interest?
   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As mentioned, *D* is a **dense range image** meaning that for any pixel location ***x*** in *D* where ***x*** = [x y]<sup>T</sup>, *D(**x**)* is the depth at pixel location ***x*** (or simply *D(x, y)*).
2. Estimating the optimal Gradient in a least-square sense

Suppose we have the following neighborhood around the depth value 5 in *D(**x**)* for some ***x***:

```
8   1   6
3   5   7
4   9   2
```

Then, using the Taylor expansion

*d**x***<sup>T</sup>.***grad(x)*** + **error** = *D(**x** + **dx**) - D(**x**)*

we get eight equations for the neighborhood points

```
[1   0]g + e = 7 - 5
[-1  0]g + e = 3 - 5
[0   1]g + e = 9 - 5
[0  -1]g + e = 1 - 5
[1   1]g + e = 2 - 5
[1  -1]g + e = 6 - 5
[-1  1]g + e = 4 - 5
[-1 -1]g + e = 8 - 5
```

that we can represent in matrix form *Ag + e = b* as

```
[1  0;-1  0;0  1;0 -1;1 1;1 -1;-1 1;-1 -1]g + e= [2;-2;4;-4;-3;1;-1;3]
```

Then minimize the squared error
***||Ag - b||<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>***. The analytical solution for *g<sup>^</sup>* that minimizes this error is of the form

***g<sup>^</sup> = (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>T</sup>b***

Comment: so the higher order terms ( _h.o.t_ ) of eq (8) can just be ignored?

Comment: @boogiedoll We don't ignore the h.o.t. We find a gradient that minimizes the squared L2 norm of h.o.t (the **error** or the **e**).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Do you have any idea how to deal with the edges? where some of the 8 neighbors have big value (background)?

Comment: @boogiedoll Carefully read the paragraph that is immediately below the part that you have quoted in your question. I'm quoting the part that answers your question: 'Inspired by bilateral filtering, we ignore the contributions of pixels whose **depth difference with the central pixel is above a threshold**. In practice, this approach effectively smooths out quantization noise on the surface, **while still providing meaningful surface normal estimates around strong depth discontinuities**'. So impose a threshold.

Comment: What if I want 3D coordinates? In this method we only solve for the x and the y components. Is it fair to set the normal to (normal_x, normal_y, 1) and then normalize?

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto I think you are asking about the point X calculated by equation (9) in the question. To my understanding, after calculating X, X1 and X2 using equations 9, 10, and 11, they calculate the surface normal that corresponds to point X.