# Normals from projective depth

Tags: python, projective-geometry

I want to compute a normal map `N(i,j)` from a depth map `D(i,j)`, where `(i,j)` describes 2D pixel location. A basic case of this problem is discussed here: [Calculate surface normals from depth image using neighboring pixels cross product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644101/calculate-surface-normals-from-depth-image-using-neighboring-pixels-cross-produc)

In my case, however, `D(i,j)` is *projective* depth: A 3D object (given by a set of 3D points) is projected onto a 2D image using an intrinsic camera matrix `[K|0]` (see below for a definition) by multiplying each 3D point in homogeneous coordinates (i.e., a 4D vector `[x,y,z,1].T`) with `[K|0]`. In this case, `D(i,j)` corresponds to the norm of the 3D point whose projection hit pixel `(i,j)`.

The intrinsic camera matrix is given by

```
[K|0] = |fx  0  ox 0|
        | 0 fy  oy 0|
        | 0  0   1 0|
```

where fx/fy are focal lengths along the x/y axes and ox/oy are camera offsets along the x/y axes.

Given this setup, what are the normals `N(i,j)`?

Comment: Could you solve this? Doesn't the normalization step make it an ill-posed problem, in which case, you'll need extra constraints, such as an image from a different angle solve this?